# How to run commands/scripts outside of Nvim?

Tags: vim, neovim, coc.nvim

This is a rewrite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46097571) question. For me this is a difficult question to put in words, please let me know if this is still unclear.

I wish I could run scripts in NVIM like in VIM, by running scripts outside the editor and not in the internal NVIM terminal emulator.

For example, listing files with `ls`

Running running `: !ls` on vim:

[image: Vim :!ls]

Result: It places the the editor in the background, as if I had typed `CTRL-Z`. I need to type a key to bring the editor back to the foreground. This is how I like it, because I can quickly go back to the terminal and see what was the result of my command, if I want to.

[image: Vim :!ls result]

Running running `: !ls` on vim:

[image: Nvim :!ls]

It opens a quick fix. Not what I want.

[image: Nvim :!ls result]

Using `:termial ls`

[image: Nvim :terminal ls]

It opens a terminal emulator. I can see the advantages for it. I can easily copy/paste from the terminal buffer, or keep it around. It is just not what I want for the most part.

[image: Nvim :terminal ls result]

Do you know how this could be achieved?

Comment: Short answer: go and use Vim instead.

Comment: Some people also had that discussion on the VI stack exchange: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19705/how-can-i-emulate-shell-command-in-neovim